# Include_once error while uploading my custom made wp plugin on webhosting

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to upload my plugin on my hosting. It successfully uploads it and installs but i am getting an error after uploading it. There is something wrong with the path. I am newbie to wordpress stuff. I have wordpress 3.8.1 installed on my localhost xampp server  where i developed the plugin. I also have the same wordpress version installed on my hosting.

```
Warning: include_once(/home/hamarawa/public_html/wordpress/wp-config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/hamarawa/public_html/wp-content/plugins/auc_result_fetcher/auc_result_fetcher.php on line 14

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/home/hamarawa/public_html/wordpress/wp-config.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/hamarawa/public_html/wp-content/plugins/auc_result_fetcher/auc_result_fetcher.php on line 14
```

There is something wrong with the path. cpanel details right now. All i have is admin panels username and password.

The line 14 contains this line of code.

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wordpress/wp-config.php' );
```

I cannot figure out what is going on. Please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that `/public_html/wordpress/wp-config.php` simply does not exist. Are you sure you supplied the correct path?

Comment: actually the problem is, i do not have my cpanel login and password. If somebody knows where does this file exists. That would be great and i will be able to make it work.

Comment: Can you please tell me where does this file exist if you install the wordpress on hosting? and my `wordpress version is 3.8.1`

Comment: What host do you use?

Comment: i removed this line `include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wordpress/wp-config.php' );` and the error is gone. Plugin is successfully installed and active now. But it does not showing on the page. It contains a form. I added the `[search_form]` shortcode a in a page but the form is not displaying on the page.